# Проверка гипотезы о равновероятности распределения ГПСЧ: смысл эксперементального значения Хи-квадрат

Tags: python-3.x, статистика, генерация-случайных-данных, статический-анализ

Есть гпсч на основе [линейного конгруэнтного метода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Нужно проверить гипотезу о равновероятности распределения полученных с помощью генератора значений выборок. Написал такую функцию:

```
def xi_check(num_array):
    intervals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(len(num_array)):
        intervals[num_array[i]//10] += 1
    xi_2_theor = [0, 3.33, 5.9, 8.34, 11.4, 16.9, 100] # квантили Хи-квадрат
    xi_2_inter = [1, 0.95, 0.75, 0.50, 0.25, 0.05, 0]  # уровень значимости
    xi_2_exp = 0
    for i in range(len(intervals)):
        xi_2_exp = xi_2_exp + ((float(intervals[i]) / float(len(num_array))
        - 0.1) ** 2) / 0.1
    for i in range(6):
        if xi_2_theor[i] <= xi_2_exp <= xi_2_theor[i+1]:
            return f"{xi_2_inter[i]} - {xi_2_inter[i+1]}", xi_2_exp
        else:
            return "Error", xi_2_exp
```

Если на выходе я получаю эксперементальное значение Хи-квадрат в промежутке между 11.4 и 16.9, то что это означает для меня? Можно ли полагаться на то, что ГПСЧ пораждает равновероятные значения последовательности?

Иными словами, я не могу понять, как можно трактовать уровень значимости. Как из него получить вероятность достоверности?
1 - (уровень значимости)?

Comment: А Вы проверьте метод. Задайте заведомо неравновероятную выборку, например константы. И поглядите, что даст Вам критерий Хи-квадрат. :-) А потом возьмите заведомо равномерную выборку, например из таблиц хорошего случ. генератора. И снова поглядите, что даст Вам критерий Хи-квадрат.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Это хорошая идея, спасибо) Сегодня утром тоже подумал, что стоит так поступить

Comment: Еще наверное можно найти в сети таблицы для гауссовского распределения от хорошего генератора и их проверить на гипотезу равномерности. При правильной работе метод должен показать, что распределение неравномерное.

Comment: Если не секрет - проверка гипотезы по Хи-квадрат это у Вас учебная задача или реальная?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не секрет) это вопрос с собеса) Каким образом можно проверить гипотезу равновероятности исходов последовательности, сгенерированной ГПСЧ) Сразу пришла идея воспользоваться численным методом Монте Карло, на что меня попросили еще варианты) И тут я слился

Comment: Проверка на заведомо неравновероятной последовательности внесла еще больше непонимания. Получил допустимые значения Хи-квадрат)

Comment: Значит что-то неправильно. Можно еще попробовать взять заведомо работающий метод проверки по Хи-квадрат и проверить на нем. Заведомо работающий метод проверки по Хи-квадрат скорее всего есть в разных математических пакетах типа матлаба.

Answer (score 2):

Проверка, которую вы задумали провести,  в общем случае называется «проверка выборки на соответствии теоретическому закону распределения». Может выполняться множеством разных методов  -  Колмогорова-Смирнова, Крамера-фон Мизеса, Джинни ….. и  в том числе с помощью использования ХИ-квадрат критерия согласия Пирсона. Суть ее в том, что вы высчитываете некую статистику и сравниваете с тем значением, которое она (статистика) бы имела, если  бы ваша выборка соответствовала бы  теоретическому закону.  В случае использование  ХИ-квадрат критерия в качестве такой  статистики используется ХИкв.практ= СУММА по количеству квантилей ((Ni-Ei)**2)/Ei)   (обратите внимание,  это несколько отлично от формулы, которую вы используете в программе).

Затем происходит сравнение ХИкв.практ со значением, взятым из таблицыХИкв.крит. при выбранном значении уровня значимости и заданном значением степени свободы. Если полученное значение , меньше значения  ХИкв.крит (альфа, df), то считается, что со степенью значимости («уверенности») альфа   ваша выборка не отличается от теоретического (в данном случае - равномерного) распределения.

Замечание 1. Иметь таблицу распределений сегодня уже не является обязательным – практически все инструменты – от Python до EXCEL – содержат функции, которые эти значения определяют самостоятельно. По той же причине и нет необходимости огород городить с самостоятельным Монте-Карло-моделированием.

Замечание 2. Для анализа соответствие именно равномерному закону распределения есть и специальные критерии, например – Шермана, Неймана-Бартона и др.

Вот как-то так.